# Why don't I see conflicts in git, but ADO shows conflicts, and how to fix this?

Tags: azure-devops, git

I have already read
[How to resolve merge conflicts in Azure DevOps current UI](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9895/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-azure-devops-current-ui) but nothing there helped.
Also, no, I cannot use "Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension", I am not the admin of the box, therefore I cannot add extensions.

ADO shows there is a conflict. However if I get pull the branch I see no conflicts.

I also tried selecting the file in ADO under "Conflicts" and "Take source `<repo>`". After that ADO shows that the conflict is resolved. But when I go back to the PR, the conflict still shows.

Why am I seeing no conflicts in git, but ADO shows conflicts? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out …

Make sure you are in the branch you are trying to merge. For the example "new_branch" is the new one I made a PR for, which is merging into "dev"

```
git branch
```

Change to the correct branch if you are not in the new_branch branch

```
git checkout new_branch
```

Perform a merge

```
git merge dev
```

Find conflicts / fix

```
git conflicts
```

My problem was the dev branch had a single file called "create_new" which was old code. The new branch I created had many changes and I created a new folder called "create_new", the conflict was the folder name. This was why it was so hard to figure out what the problem was.

Check status that changes will be made on merge

```
git status
```

Commit the changes, this will create a new merge/commit, keep as is and save to push with the merge.

```
git commit -a
```

Now in ADO, the conflict is gone.